# Ghost duplicate annotations

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to create a bar chart with annotations on the right hand side. I can achieve this with the below code but it also produces some bonus ghost annotations that move when the size of the chart changes. What am I missing here?

```
    library(highcharter)

    x <- rev(c(.27, .18, .03, .07)) * 100

    highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "bar", 
           backgroundColor = "#eee",
           margin = c(0, 0, 0, 0)) %>%
  hc_add_series_labels_values(labels = 1:length(x),
                              dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, 
                                                inside = FALSE,
                                                format = '{y}% ',
                                                style = list(color = "contrast",
                                                             fontSize = "14px",
                                                             textOutline = "none",
                                                             fontWeight = "normal")),
                              values = rev(x),
                              color = rep("#333333", length(x))) %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_tooltip(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_yAxis(visible = FALSE, max = 110) %>%
  hc_add_annotations(
    list(
      list(xValue = 0.5, yValue = 100, title = list(text = 'A')),
      list(xValue = 1.5, yValue = 100, title = list(text = 'B')),
      list(xValue = 2.5, yValue = 100, title = list(text = 'C'))
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi jenswirf, This problem seems to be closely related to the `R` wrapper, because your settings work correctly in javascript code: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zdvLahyp/ I think that you should contact directly with the author of the wrapper: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues